# mapbox and cloudinary images are blocked and appear blank how can i fix this?

Tags: node.js, mapbox, cloudinary

[these are the errors i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzi91.png)

https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js    blocked script-src-elem
https://res.cloudinary.com/dir8262l3/image/upload/v1642925674/YelpCamp/zcfzlvxrw2bakr7xh7t9.jpg blocked img-src campgrounds:154
https://res.cloudinary.com/dir8262l3/image/upload/v1642928841/YelpCamp/ugvpjsw6nftpufhhf9xo.jpg blocked img-src campgrounds:154
https://res.cloudinary.com/dir8262l3/image/upload/v1643223219/YelpCamp/peoctzytgriobcl6kv73.jpg blocked img-src campgrounds:154
https://res.cloudinary.com/dir8262l3/image/upload/v1643224855/YelpCamp/njcbt6dcyaijaqonwd40.jpg blocked img-src campgrounds:154
https://res.cloudinary.com/dir8262l3/image/upload/v1643597847/YelpCamp/xqmfr3ievna8wqbcn35q.jpg blocked img-src campgrounds:154

how can i fix this

Comment: Can you provide which stacks you are using ? And if possible show the code to demonstrate how you are implementing these. ? Meanwhile I'm trying to reproduce the errors myself. But it would be better if you can share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this error because of an inline event handler and will need to define `script-src-elem` in your CSP policy.

Answer (score -1):

I did a little research and found out that those errors are due to an inline event handler. You will need to define `script-src-elem` in your CSP policy.

You can find more about it from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src-elem)